# How to create an instance of a generic type in a Scala 3 macro?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm porting a macro from Scala 2 to Scala 3. As part of it's work, the Scala 2 macro creates an instance of a generic type using the default constructor. This is simple to do with a quasiquote in Scala 2, but I'm struggling with Scala 3 macros. This is my best approach so far:

```scala
import scala.quoted.*

inline def make[A <: AnyRef]: A = ${ makeThat[A] }

private def makeThat[A <: AnyRef : Type](using Quotes): Expr[A] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  '{ new A().asInstanceOf[A] }
```

Without the `.asInstanceOf[A]`, the compiler emits an error message:

```
[error] -- [E007] Type Mismatch Error: ...
[error] 17 |  '{ new A() }
[error]    |     ^^^^^^^
[error]    |Found:    Object
[error]    |Required: A
[error]    |
[error]    |where:    A is a type in method makeThat with bounds <: AnyRef
[error] one error found
```

Is there a better solution without a downcast at runtime?

**EDIT:** As of Scala 3.0.1, this doesn't even compile anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the right tree with the lower level reflect API.

```scala
import scala.quoted.*

inline def make[A <: AnyRef]: A = ${ makeThat[A] }

def makeThat[A <: AnyRef : Type](using Quotes): Expr[A] =
  import quotes.reflect.*

  TypeRepr.of[A].classSymbol.map( sym =>
    Apply(Select(New(TypeTree.of[A]), sym.primaryConstructor), Nil).asExprOf[A]
  )
  .getOrElse(???) // not a class, so can't instantiate
```

Though you should include a check to see if your constructor doesn't have parameters.

Comment: Sigh, this is so terrible in comparison to the quasiquotes in Scala 2...

Comment: Yes quotes and splices in Scala 3 only allow well-typed code, which in this case is not possible because the compiler cannot know which constructors some type `A <: AnyRef` has, if any.

Comment: If I understand, this solution hinges on their being a fixed number of arguments (none in this case). If the number of arguments varied, am I correct in thinking a [type class derivation](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/derivation-macro.html) is probably the way to go? e.g. for some trait with a method that instantiates the generic type, `A`.

Comment: @ecoe If you can go with a type class that would definitely be preferable.

Comment: @Jasper-M thanks I'm close to getting it working with type class here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73639857/scala-3-macro-for-deriving-type-class-that-instantiates-case-class